# ObjectUnsubscribedError: object unsubscribed

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, observable

**ObjectUnsubscribedError: object unsubscribed**,  when sometime(not every time) entering any value in text box

---

### HTML

```
<input #gb type="text" pInputText class="ui-widget ui-text"
[(ngModel)]="gb.value" (ngModelChange)="clearFilter(gb.value)" placeholder="Find" />
```

### component.ts

```
clearFilter(newValue) {
        this.infomessage = [];
        this.errormessage = [];
        this.isDelete = false;
        this.isDefaultLoad = false;
        if (this.oldFilterText === '' && newValue === '') {
            return false;
        }
        this.oldFilterText = newValue;
        if (this._configuration.isNullOrEmptyOrUndefined(newValue)) {
            this.sortField = '';
            if (!this._configuration.isNullOrEmptyOrUndefined(this.dataTable.sortField)) {
                this.sortField = this.dataTable.sortField;
            }
            this.dataTable.reset();
            this.tempFilteredRecords = [];
            this.getApprovalTypelist();
            this.dataTable.sortField = this.sortField;
            this.dataTable.sortMode = 'single';
            this.dataTable.sortOrder = this.sortOrder;
        }
    }
```

My code working good! but Sometime am getting  a error when type in the text box. Also `clearFilter` does not fire after getting this error.

*error*: ***ObjectUnsubscribedError: object unsubscribed***

> I have tried this(But I don't know these below links related with my defects or not)  below discussions

[Angular 2 object unsubscribed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015165/angular-2-object-unsubscribed-error)

[ObjectUnsubscribedError when trying to prevent subscribing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38081878/objectunsubscribederror-when-trying-to-prevent-subscribing-twice)

[Exception: ObjectUnsubscribedError when working with Observables with RxJS and Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35579662/exception-objectunsubscribederror-when-working-with-observables-with-rxjs-and-a)

[ObjectUnsubscribedError when trying to prevent subscribing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38081878/objectunsubscribederror-when-trying-to-prevent-subscribing-twice)

> **But everything does not helps to me. Kindly take me out of this unpredictable defect :(**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the answer, I have just unsubscribe the `onFilter()` event by using this below code

```
this.dataTable.onFilter.unsubscribe();
```

Thanks for the views!